# Error in Photoshop cs5 when trying to export layers to files

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, photoshop-cs5

I always get this

> Error: General Photoshop error occurred. This functionality may not be available in this version of Photoshop.

and then it has another message below. This time it was

> The object “document 71” is not currently available.

But I've seen other ones. Any thoughts? It was doing this on my Macbook, and I just got a Macbook Pro, and it does the same thing.